# Presenting negative numbers using parentheses: where does this practice come from?

Tags: financial-literacy, accounting, financial-statements, history

The standard accounting way is always to show negative numbers in parentheses. Where does this practice come from?

For example, this  [cash flow statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cash_flow_statement&oldid=764348133) use parentheses indicate negative values:

[image]

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer This is a question about personal finance as I write a cash flow statement on my own finance every year.

Comment: But the question itself is about history. Why a notation came to be isn't a PF question.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer [What is our stance on questions aimed at understanding the origin of notations used in personal finance?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2457/5656)

Comment: Questions about accounting fit in the Accounting proposal in Area 51! https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113560/accounting?referrer=FNOG9_mXNYnhlAdnl9FE8w2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd love to see if someone can find a convincing origin story for the practice, but I believe it became adopted simply because parenthesis stand out more than a negative sign.

Think of a hand-written ledger or balance sheet, an errant dot of the pen could look like a minus sign, or a narrow column could leave too little space for the minus sign to be noticeable. Parenthesis are deliberate and easy to spot while scanning a sheet, so no idea who was the first to do it, but it was effective and caught on.

Comment: Not my down-vote, but this Answer might be deserving for providing mere speculation when the Question asked specifically for historical fact. A Stack Exchange is not a casual discussion site or forum.

Comment: @BasilBourque That's fair, my answer was based on research that yielded no better explanation. I'm guessing the downvotes were actually related to answering a question that was deemed off-topic, but who knows. Always like feedback!

Comment: Down-voting an Answer because the Question was deemed off-topic would be quite petty, unless the Question was quite obviously irrelevant/useless (not the case here). Anyways, in my experience you can always expect an occasional nonsensical down-vote. I suspect some are just a “drive-by down-vote” by a cranky person, or perhaps even an accident such as a clumsy-thumb in the iOS *Stack Overflow* app.