# Numbers in parentheses in financial statements?

Tags: financial-literacy, financial-statements

In financial statements numbers are sometimes given with parentheses around them, while other numbers appear without parentheses. What does it mean if a number is enclosed by parentheses?

Comment: Related: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/80187/

Comment: @DStanley Too bad the question got closed by 1 admin...

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Agreed, and I voted to re-open the question since financial statement analysis _is_ on-topic per [this meta question](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2636)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It means the number is *negative*. It's an alternate way of showing negative numbers versus prefacing with a negative sign (`-`)

In some cases, a negative value also has a different name. For example you'll often see

```
Net Profit (Loss) :   (10,000)
```

Where the parentheses means that it was a loss and not a profit. Mathematically it's the same as a "negative profit" but it is used to keep headings consistent (it would be harder to analyze than if you used a different heading to indicate a profit or a loss).

Comment: And as info: the reason this is done is because "()" is WAY better to see - particualrly historically when print quality may be dubious at times - than a "-" before the number. Less possibility for mistakes.

Comment: To me, this is way less intuitive than simply using a negative sign

Comment: @KolobCanyon As the comment states, intuition is not the goal, clarity is. Many finance rules go back before computers, where a negative sign might be missed or even just misinterpreted. In the finance world, the use of parentheses is pretty universally understood.